# Eliminating the need for "controller" in the filename of a Zend Framework controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, filenames

How do I eliminate the need for the "Controller" suffix in the filename of a Zend Framework controller? It just gets tiresome to keep typing that suffix in when creating controllers, and meanwhile the file is already in a controllers folder so it's superfluous.

For instance, by default the homepage on a site goes to "controllers/IndexController.php". What if I want it to go to "controllers/Index.php"?

Comment: Not to be glib, but is this really that much of a hardship? How many controllers are you going to make that it's going to cost you actual productivity typing those ten letters each time you create a controller?

Comment: No problem. I'm just picky, that's all.

Comment: Don't do that. Often there will be cases when need to give a Controller and Model same name (ex: Product).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. Good point, Presario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latter portion of the class name is hardcoded to "Controller" in `Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Abstract::formatControllerName()`.

To change it, you'd have to create a custom Dispatcher class that implements `Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Interface` and override the `formatControllerName()` function.  Then assign an instance of your new Dispatcher to the front controller in your bootstrap script with `$frontController->setDispatcher()` before you call `dispatch()`.

Why would you need to change the format of a controller class name anyway?  It's not like that PHP file appears in a request URL anywhere.

Sounds like you're [bikeshedding](http://bikeshed.com/).

Comment: Eh, its an interesting thought experiment at least.  When originally looking at ZF, I found the fact that controllers/models/etc broke from the traditional naming scheme (PEAR style, where it goes from least-to-most-specific) pretty odd, where the rest of ZF followed that.  So, if you're stuck wanting to name your controllers like MyApp_Controller_Action_Index - you can, with the above.